# MSSQL how do I query sql for a latest state record after latest date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with openingdays, location, state (Open, Day Closed, Shift Closed) and the actual date. I would like to know when the day is closed for the last time (state = D) and everything what happens after that date (state Opened, Shift Closed) for the specific location.

```
location  day          state  actual_date
-----------------------------------------------------
ams,      2015-11-25,  O      2015-11-25 12:20:59.000
ams,      2015-11-25,  D      2015-11-26 02:10:00.000
ams,      2015-11-26,  O      2015-11-26 12:20:59.000
ams,      2015-11-26,  D      2015-11-27 02:10:00.000
sch,      2015-11-25,  O      2015-11-25 14:12:27.000
sch,      2015-11-25,  D      2015-11-26 03:23:13.000
sch,      2015-11-26,  O      2015-11-26 14:12:27.000
sch,      2015-11-26,  S      2015-11-26 18:26:24.000
```

What I would like to have is

```
ams,      2015-11-26,  D      2015-11-27 02:10:00.000
ams,      2015-11-26,  O      2015-11-26 12:20:59.000
sch,      2015-11-26,  S      2015-11-26 18:26:24.000
sch,      2015-11-26,  O      2015-11-26 14:12:27.000
sch,      2015-11-25,  D      2015-11-26 03:23:13.000
sch,      2015-11-25,  O      2015-11-25 14:12:27.000
```

I already created this:

```
SELECT k.location, k.day, k.state, k.actual_date
FROM myTable k
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT state, max(day) as MaxDate
    FROM myTable k2
    GROUP BY state
) k2 ON k.state = k2.state AND k.day = k2.MaxDate
```

Which outputs everything on the latest day, but it wont show me the results on the days after the latest Day Closed (state = D).

Comment: Do you mean "for *a* specific location" i.e. *ams* or "for *each* location"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.. was actually very easy..

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE day >= ( SELECT max(day) 
            FROM [dbo].[myTable]
            WHERE state = 'D'
            AND location = 'ams'
)
ORDER BY [location] DESC, [actual_date] DESC
```

Thanks anyway for looking up to my issue.

Comment: I would have thought this would return two rows for ams and two for sch, which is not what the question lists as desired output.

Comment: Well.. it shouldn't.. it will take everything on the last date when it had state = 'D' and everything above. It will also take everything on the day of state D itself, but that isnt a problem for me.

Comment: Shouldn't or doesn't? I don't have a copy of sql server to hand just now.

Comment: The inner query will return one value - 2015-11-26. The outer will return rows with a greater or equal value - rows 3, 4, 7 & 8 from the example data. Two for ams and two for sch.

Comment: You're right.. This won't give the desired output. But it solved my issue. I will modify the question so it will fit in the answer. I have a where clause in the inner query for location so it will only take sch or ams. In that case.. the inner query results in 2015-11-25 for sch and 2015-11-26 for ams.